# Null Reference Exception while doing conditional formatting for radgrid

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I am currently attempting to modify the way my radgrid displays data by highlighting specific rows which has went over my "overdue" limit. here's a snippet of the methods i am using...

ASPX

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TimeCreated" HeaderText="Posted On" ReadOnly="true" UniqueName="TimeCreated"/>
```

C# Method 1

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

        string time = dataItem["TimeCreated"].Text;
        DateTime timePosted = DateTime.Parse(time);
        TimeSpan allowance = new TimeSpan(0, 25, 0);
        DateTime overdue = timePosted.Add(allowance);

        if (DateTime.Now > overdue)
        {
            dataItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
            dataItem.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```

C# Method 2

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem; 
        TimeSpan allowance = new TimeSpan(0, 25, 0);

        if (DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(dataItem["TimeCreated"].Text).Add(allowance), DateTime.Now) > 0)
        {
            dataItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
            dataItem.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```

C# Method 3

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
        TimeSpan allowance = new TimeSpan(0, 25, 0);


        if (DateTime.Parse(dataItem["TimeCreated"].Text).Add(allowance) > DateTime.Now )
        {
            dataItem.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
            dataItem.Font.Bold = true;
        }
    }
```

All of these methods pproduces the same exact NullReferenceException which is unfathomable to me, i hope someone could shed some light on this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I missed an if statement to bind the grid row cell of my intended column...

here's the correct method

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem) // bind the intended column cells
        {
            GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            TimeSpan allowance = new TimeSpan(0, 25, 0);

            if (DateTime.Parse(dataItem["TimeCreated"].Text).Add(allowance) < DateTime.Now)
            {
                dataItem.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightPink;
                dataItem.Font.Bold = true;
            }
        }
    }
```